# How to pass data from multiple views to one?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, view

In my main controller I have multiple labels and I have seven more views and with each of them I need to pass a variable to the main one and fill one of those labels. Now my problem is that when I send one variable and it fills a label and then I go to a different page and try to send a variable from that one it fills a separate label, as intended, but it also deletes the text from the other label. Here's what I've been doing:

This code is on one of the secondary views (not the one with the labels)

```
var cpu: String = ""

@IBAction func intel8350k(_ sender: UIButton) {
    cpu = "Intel Core i3 8350k"

    if cpu != "" {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "seuge",  sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var mainController = segue.destination as! ViewController
    mainController.cpuString = cpu
}
```

On the main view with the labels:

```
var cpuString = ""

@IBOutlet weak var cpuLabel: UILabel!

cpuLabel.text = cpuString
```

With the other views I want to send data from its pretty much the same except the variables are replaced (e.g. cpuString is coolerString).

Comment: Structs are best options For this or you can make use of NSUserDefaults Preferred Structs

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the ways in which you can pass data between view controllers:

1. when a segue is performed
2. triggering transitions programmatically in your code
3. through the state of the app
4. using singletons
5. using the app delegate
6. assigning a delegate to a view controller
7. through unwind segues
8. referencing a view controller directly
9. using the user defaults
10. through notifications

Answer (score 0):

In current situation, I think you can simply use global variables to hold those multiple values that you want to pass in different pages / controllers.

Create a new file called "Global.swift"

```
struct Global {
    static var cpu = ""
    static var memory = ""
}
```

So in many controller you can easily use to store and get the data as below.

```
// set the value
Global.cpu = "20.0"
Global.memory = "0.4"

// get value
print(Global.cpu)
```

Take note this variable will be reset every time you run the apps.

Comment: Don't really get it (sorry, new to swift). Do I replace the whole prepare for segue thing or do I use it with the segue thing? When I tried changing the values I couldn't do it like in your example. Gave me this error:         
                                                                                                            
'Instance member 'cpu' cannot be used on type 'CPU_ViewController.Global''

Comment: just set the value when button is clicked or anywhere, and it can be used in another controller. not necessary to set value in segue